# convergate and limit of a series, using geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have to show, that this series convergates and determine its limit.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^{2n+3}}$

Well, i tried to transform it into a Geometric series, but i dont really know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^{2n+3}}=\frac{1}{5^3}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^{2n}}=\frac{1}{125}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{25^{n}}$$

Comment: so its $\frac{1}{125} * \frac {1}{1-\frac{1}{25}} = \frac{1}{125} * \frac {25}{24} = \frac {1}{120}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.